# Including dependency from imported maven library

Tags: java, maven, gradle

A little fuzzy on Gradle/maven, but generally here is the idea.

I have a web application that uses a common library (A) as a dependency with source implemented under com.mydomain.utils package. There is another legacy package (B) written under a different namespace, com.mydomain.legacy, that I would like included within A, such that when I include A as a dependency in my primary application, library B's resources can be resolved as normal:

`import com.mydomain.legacy.someutility`

Comment: An import has absolutely nothing to do with library dependencies and downloading them. All it does is allowing you to use List instead of java.util.List in your source code. If A is published in a Maven repo and has B in its dependencies inside its published pom.xml, then adding a dependency to A in your Maven/gradle web application project will also bring its B dependency.

Comment: Is package (B) part of library (A)? If not, is package (B) available as a Maven dependency? It would be very helpful for us if you can post some sample pom.xml.

Comment: Are you able to build A with maven?

Answer (score -1):

If B is a dependency of A, and A is a maven artifact, then B is already included in A, otherwise, it would not be possible to build A.

If B is not a dependency of A, then you need to list both A and B as dependencies of your project.

Comment: No, libraries don't include the code of the libraries that they depend on. Maybe that's not what you mean, but your terminology is confusing.

Comment: I never said anything about the code. If B is a dependency of A then it is listed in the pom.xml of A. That means that A is able to obtain the library of B, otherwise, A can't build.

Comment: You said "then B is included in A". This is extremely confusing.

Comment: It is included as a dependency in the pom. This is how maven works.

Comment: Regarding your last comment. Again: not everybody uses Maven to publish Maven artifacts and build JVM libraries. Many, many people don't. Many people thus manage dependencies without using Maven at all.

Comment: Sorry. It's indeed confusing. I meant *artifact*. Can you now please fix your answer?